# How to pass an object as a parameter to another function in Rust?

Tags: rust

This is my code:

```
use handlebars::{Handlebars};
use serde_json::json;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;

pub const base_path: &str = "/Users/myname/Desktop/projectname/";

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>{

    let mut reg = Handlebars::new();

    // problem zone: how to pass the reg object here?
    //register_template_files(reg);

    Ok(())
}

// using registry object
fn register_template_files(registry: registry) {
    //using object of type Registry to register Templates
}
```

I don't know Rust good enough to know how to pass the `reg` object to another function. How to do this?

Comment: Take your time to read the **free** official book: [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `registry: registry`, you need to use `registry: Registry` and import that type from handlebars.

You probably also want to use references `registry: &Registry`, because what looks like pass-by-value instead is the notation for move semantics in Rust, which basically means that any value you pass into a function is thereafter no longer valid and trying to do that will provoke errors from the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I tried some other things googling but it seems that Registry is something like a generic type like Registry<&str>. I gave up and I think I really need to pick up the "rusty way" first before using it. Imports and generics work way different than I am used to. It was far easier to switch to Swift being used to Objective C and Java. I will come back later.